# How to print an ArrayList of ArrayLists so that each inner list is printed on one row?

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring, pretty-print

I have an ArrayList of ArrayLists - something like `ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>>`.
Since I get this as a return value from a function, after every call a different size is called. I am wondering how to display its elements is such a way that the inner ArrayList constitutes one row and so for every row.

What would be my required parameter(s) for the for loop? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for (List<Node> l1 : arrayLists) {
   for (Node n : l1) {
       System.out.print(n + " "); 
   }

   System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> ls;
    //initialize ls and set values in it...
    //after set some values, let's print it
    for(List<String> innerLs : ls) {
        String[] arr = innerLs.toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
    }
}
```

It should be the same logic for `List<List<T>>`.

Answer (score 0):

invoke `iterator()` which will return an `Iterator<ArrayList<Node>>`, and loop on that.

Inside the loop invoke `iterator()` again, on each iterated elements, which will return a `Iterator<Node>`; use an inner loop and use `next()` on it to display.

For the loops use either a 'foreach' loop (`for(Node n : iterator)`) or a while loop (`while(iterator.hasNext())`).